# How to use C++11, C++14 and C++1z tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

I guess the best answer would be something like:

> Use them when you ask about features introduced in each standard, or questions about the standard itself.

But I sometimes use them when I want to explicitly state that I'm ok with using features of all of them, and my compiler will support them. Is this ok?

*P.S.: I know C++1z is not out, but last version of clang implements some of its features.*

Comment: I actually wish the tags branched out to legacy instead of to present -- i.e., the `c++` tag would always encompass the latest version of c++, while the introduction of c++11 would introduce a c++03 tag instead of a c++11 tag.